# What happens if you bridge two connections to the same network on Windows

Tags: windows, networking

What happens (or is likely to happen) on a Windows network, if a computer on the network has its Wifi and Ethernet bridged, and both get connected to the same network. Does anything happen? Does it make a difference if there are more switches (or computers) on the network? Does the whole thing crash and burn, or does nothing even notice? Does the IP subnet mask make any difference?

Comment: You should be able to easily test this to answer most of these questions and the operation does not seem to be a risky one either. Are there are reasons you'd be reluctant to just trying it and looking over the configurations, etc. to confirm?

Answer (score 0):

If your networking gear supports the Spanning Tree Protocol (STP, part of IEEE 802.1D), then it will detect and defeat the network loop you created, and everything will be okay.

If your networking gear doesn't support STP, then you'll have created a networking loop and packets (at least multicasts/broadcasts) will loop around and around in the network, destroying network bandwidth until you break the loop.